# json_encode output formatting for highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, variables, syntax

I'm using this code to bring a php var into a js function but I can't seem to get the proper formatting (output). I think highcharts needs numbers but it is creating a string even if I use "intval".

```
series: [{
            name: 'Spyware',
            data: [0, 3, 0, 0, 0]
        }, {
            name: 'Viruses',
            data: [ <?php echo json_encode(intval($virusNum)); ?> , 0, 0, 0, 0] 
        }, {
            name: 'Brute Force Attacks',
            data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        }, {
            name: 'Host Sweeps',
            data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        }, {
            name: 'Anonymizer/Proxy Server',
            data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        }]
```

Here's where I create the $virusNum variable.

```
$viruses[$aPos] = intval($freq);
$virusNum = $virusNum + $viruses[$aPos];
```

Comment: why do you use the json_encode function?

Comment: JSON is always string, you need to `JSON.parse` the `json_encode`ed result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why json-encode there? This is just an integer value, so there is no need for that.

```
data: [ <?php echo intval($virusNum); ?> , 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: good habit to get into, if nothing else. kind of like writing secure sql queries, even if you know there's no possibility of an injection problem.

Comment: @MarcB I suppose. But I think relying on non-standard, library-specific JSON encoding behaviors, such as how primitives are encoded/decoded when they are not within an appropriate data structure (object or array) - something not covered by the JSON specification - is just as bad.

Comment: This doesn't work either. - Wanted to add this as I just saw the 2 comments appear after saving this comment that I'm a php noob so those comments are greek to me. Thx anyway.

Comment: @RandyMCode what does `var_dump($virusNum)` produce? Also, this code you show that produces the javascript output is being served up by a PHP page right (i.e. this isn't in some javascript include somewhere)?

Comment: `var_dump($virusNum)` gives: `C:\MAMP\...\threatcharts_datafeed_2016-07-08a.php:71:int 141` - All I need is the 141. I put the "..." in the output, the result was the path to my php file.

Comment: @RandyMCode Why are you calling `intval()` on that string value?  That seem like you are going to get very unpredictable results.

Comment: Using `intval` because I need a number not a string for the data array that Highcharts uses. The number output needs to be part of the array. Maybe I need to make the array beforehand and use a variable instead of combining PHP and JavaScript on oneline.

Comment: @RandyMCode I understand why you need an integer value in javascipt, but don't understand what you think you are going to get by, in essence, doing `intval('C:\MAMP\...\threatcharts_datafeed_2016-07-08a.php:71:int 141')`  `intval()` doesn't just magically grab `141` from the end of the string.

Comment: Further experimentation yields that `<?php echo $virusNum; ?>` is working - outputting just a number. For some reason I can;t get the highcharts function to take it. Thanks Mike for all your help. +1 vote even though it doesn't count from a stackoverflow noob.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to use the `$options` parameter of the [`json_encode` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) in PHP:

```
json_encode(intval($virusNum), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)
```

> JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK (integer)
>
> Encodes numeric strings as numbers. Available since PHP 5.3.3.

Comment: What does the code look like after PHP has processed it? Does $virusNum start with a value of 0?